# How do I perform a where query for count and attribute?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am essentially trying to convert this statement into SQL :

```
Member.all.select{|e|e.quizzes.present? && e.quizzes.any?{|q|!q.completed} }
```

So far I have this :

```
Member.joins(:quizzes).group("enterprise_members.id HAVING count(quizzes.id) > 0")
```

But this does not take into account scoping my query by *just quizzes that have not been set to complete*

How would I do this?

Comment: Try this: `Member.includes(:quizzes).where('quizzes.id IS NOT NULL')`

Comment: I guess you can just call `to_sql` with your first query so that it gives you an idea to write second query.

Comment: @Pavan the first is not a SQL query, `to_sql` won't work. Ruby is doing all the work, not SQL (for the first statement)

Comment: @MrYoshiji Ofcourse,it is not SQL query.I'm trying to say that `to_sql` converts an Active Record query to SQL query.

Comment: @Pavan You can't put `.to_sql` at the end of a Ruby call..

Comment: @Pavan You don't understand the basics of Rails scoping, and the use of `to_sql`. after triggering the SQL to perform the query, like doing  `.select{}`, you can't call `.to_sql` because after doing the `.select` it is no longer an ActiveRecord::Relation (Rails scoping!) but an Array!

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thanks for that! I will keep in mind.And take my apologies.

Comment: Ahah don't worry @Pavan no need for an apology! I'm glad that I taught you something new :) Which is my principal goal on this website

Comment: @MrYoshiji And I'm glad too to know something that i didn't know before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work?

```
Member.joins(:quizzes).where('quizzes.completed = ?', false)
```

this will return members that have at least one uncompleted quiz.  Note this assumes that nulls are not allowed as a value for completed.  If nulls are allowed then you would have to say

```
Member.joins(:quizzes).where('quizzes.completed is null or quizzes.completed = ?', false)
```

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're after.  It would be helpful if you described the required results in english rather than/as well as code.

Comment: Is that group call not needed then?

Comment: I don't think so but like i said i'm not 100% sure what your requirement is.

Comment: Thanks Max so much. I had to append at the end my `.group` statement to make fit perfectly. I really appreciate your response!